# How to get access to embedded assembly's metadata using IMetaDataDispenser.OpenScope?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, compiler-construction, pdb-files

I have a .NET solution which consists of several projects. It's possible to say that one of these projects is logically a primary one and all others are secondary. Our team has decided to build the project the next way. The main project will produce an assembly (I'll refer it to as Primary). All other projects' assemblies are Secondary and they will be embedded as a resource into the Primary one.

The `SourceCodeForExceptionHelper` class in the Primary project is responsible for getting the original source code using PDB files on every encountered exception. To do that I use the approach described [here](http://sorin.serbans.net/blog/index.php/2010/08/10/how-to-read-pdb-files/). It worked correctly in my separate proof of concept project. But when I tried to move that class into the real solution I've encountered a problem: the `IMetaDataDispenser.OpenScope` method requires not null reference to assembly file's path. Surely, I haven't such a reference for any of Secondary assembly (because their files are embedded in the Primary). For that reason I can't create an object of the type `ISymbolReader` and read the source code. How can I solve that problem? By the way, the problem is even worse because we embed only Secondary assemblies without their PDB files (though we will do it if it is necessary).

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

Comment: Can't you just output the resource as a physical file on disk (maybe with a cache mechanism, so next time, it's fast) before you call OpenScope?

Comment: @Simon Thank you for the reply. Yes, I and my colleagues discussed an idea of embedding both assemblies and pdb files in Primary assembly. After that we are able to store the copy of these files on disk when required. But we have agreed that this solution is a little bit strange. Also, it will be hard to explain through the code to the reader WHY we do so. That's why I've posted my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using the .NET Framework builtin functions, as they rely on physical files. However, there is a solution using the [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library, as it has an overloads that takes a Stream as input instead of a file path for its symbols reader.

Here is an example of a Console app named "TestPdb" which dumps its IL code to the console, including PDB information:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using Mono.Cecil.Pdb;

namespace TestPdb
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // we use a Stream for the assembly
            AssemblyDefinition asm;
            using (FileStream asmStream = new FileStream("testpdb.exe", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(asmStream);
            }

            // we use a Stream for the PDB
            using (FileStream symbolStream = new FileStream("testpdb.pdb", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                asm.MainModule.ReadSymbols(new PdbReaderProvider().GetSymbolReader(asm.MainModule, symbolStream));
            }

            TypeDefinition type = asm.MainModule.GetType("TestPdb.Program");

            foreach (MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method:" + method.Name);
                foreach (Instruction ins in method.Body.Instructions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + ins);
                    if (ins.SequencePoint != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  Url:" + ins.SequencePoint.Document.Url);
                        // see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/06/19/feefee-sequencepoints.aspx
                        if (ins.SequencePoint.StartLine != 0xFEEFEE)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("  StartLine:" + ins.SequencePoint.StartLine + " StartColumn:" + ins.SequencePoint.StartColumn);
                            Console.WriteLine("  EndLine:" + ins.SequencePoint.EndLine + " EndColumn:" + ins.SequencePoint.EndColumn);
                        }
                        // etc...
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: since you only need to read from PDBs, you can recompile the Cecil library defining the READ_ONLY conditional symbol to save some bytes. You can also embed Cecil source code directly in your assemblies, no need to use the .DLL versions.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I have tried to create the stream for the embedded assembly. After that I use the pdb file which is accessible on hard drive. But I have no success with creation a TypeDefinition object. I'll try to play with that code more.

Btw, in my original sample I'm able to retrieve the real source code on C# (not IL). Is it hard to improve the solution for doing the same? I don't ask you the solution itself but some references to related articles because Mono.Cecil has too few docs.

Comment: @keykeeper - TypeDefinition is just part of Mono Cecil. To get the C# source code, it's exactly the same as in the sample. The SequencePoint contains a Document and the Url points to the C# source file. You can reuse the same StreamReader principle to read the file.

Comment: Thank you for refering to Document and Url properties of the SequencePoint class. It works fine in general. But I've met a trouble opening a source code file when it's moved (i.e. when the Url property points to wrong location). Is it possible to get access to the original source code avoiding opening the .cs file  which is refered by Url?

Comment: @keykeeper - This is called "source indexing". You can google on this. for example: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx or http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/04/svn-source-indexing-to-codeplex.html