# How to read .net assembly's meta data table

Tags: metadata, clr

I'm reading Jeffery Richter's book "CLR via C#". He mentioned the CLR metadata table contains TypeRef and MemberRef section.

I want to build a call graph by reading these MemberRef and TypeRef information. What is the best way to do so? After a search, I found somebody read the file directly using PE/CLR file format. Somebody use native IMetaDataImport. I wonder if there is any .net built-int classes or 3rd party libraries to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you need this...?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer To get a dependency map for instance.

Comment: Ellaborate more on this, please. Do it as part of your question's body so we can know what's your actual goal...

Comment: @CodingSiberian, there's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx for assembly-level references. You can use the Module.ResolveXxx methods if you have actual tokens you want to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see metadata you can use ILDasm.exe.

Example: ILDasm.exe D: \ MyTestAsm.dll

Next: view -> meta info -> we Show!

If you want to receive data from the code, you can research 3rd party library Mono:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/

MetaData it is part of IL-code. If you want to see Il code you can see this:
[How to get access to embedded assembly's metadata using IMetaDataDispenser.OpenScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570260/how-to-get-access-to-embedded-assemblys-metadata-using-imetadatadispenser-opens)

Comment: If you just want to see the metadata I can recommend JetBrains dotPeek as an alternative to ILDasm.exe. https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/